# How to not show calendar events from group in Exchange/Outlook

Tags: email

I am using Outlook 2016.

I am in an email group and my company has a stupid policy where any meeting events made should include this emailgroup as an attendee. So thousands of meetings invite come to my inbox. I created a rule so that the emails sent to that group are moved to a specific folder. But they still show up in my calendar. You know what this looks like if I want to see what my schedule is like.

How do I make it so that the calendar would not show these events, unless my personal email is included as an attendee?

Comment: Perhaps you should not show up to an important meeting, then when asked to explain your absence, show you boss your calendar.

Answer (score 1):

You simply want to filter the invites on your calendar view.

Firstly, I'm presuming you can't just turn off the group's invites in your calendar? I don't care what most of my team are upto so here I have turned them all off:

[image]

If not, you can filter the calendar view -> View Settings while in the calendar view

[image: Calendar Settings]

Then in filter -> Advanced and try something like setting the Recipient Name field doesn't contain the name of the Team who's invited to every meeting.

[image: Advanced Filter]

You may need to combine rules, such as the one above along with 'Or contains my name' so you get meetings you're specifically invited to.